# Selenium: How to get list of child span elements given a xpath

Tags: java, html, selenium, testng, ui-testing

I want to get all child span elements for the following xpath

```
//label[@for='someText']/span
```

This should return me

```
<span class="someClass">"Find this text"</span>
<span id="someId">"Find this text2"</span>
```

Basically, the number of nested span elements may change dynamically, in this case we have 2 span child elements, in some cases there can just be 1 or more span elements.

Goal:
The intention behind this is to fetch the text for all those elements for comparison purposes. Once i get those elements, I can iterate through each of them and based on their attributes I can fetch data i want.

Sample HTML format:

```
<label for="someText">
  <span class="nestedClass">
    <h2 id="id">
      <span>"Hello"</span>
    </h2>
    <span class="someClass">"Find this text"</span>
    <br>
    <span id="someId">"Find this text2"</span>
  </span>
</label>
```

Is there a way I can achieve this? Could someone please help me with this or any better approach in doing this?

Thank you.

Comment: The subject is incorrect. The subject should be something like " exclude certain tags in the child elements"

Comment: @Sureshmani may be you didn't understand the question correctly, I just want to fetch child "span" elements. So, excluding certain tags is implicit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use either of the `xpath` should work for you.

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//label[@for='someText']/span/span"));
```

Or ignore span tag who's parents h2

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//label[@for='someText']/span//span[not(ancestor::h2)]"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use following XPath:

```
//label[@for="someText"]/span/*[not(*)]/text()
```

Here predicate `*[not(*)]` will filter leaf span nodes.

Comment: You can't use `text()` in locators in Selenium. It doesn't support XPath > 1.0.

Answer (score -1):

You can loop through elements using the size() or simply iterate the list using the for loop.

```
List<WebElement> mySpans = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//label[@for='someText']/span//span"));
        
        int totalSpans = mySpans.size(); // This is the total count of spans - dynamic
        
// or simply iterate the list of webelements using for loop
        for(WebElement span : mySpans)
        {
            System.out.print(span.getText());
        }
```

Comment: wouldn't this also include <h2> tag? and other direct/indirect elements?

Comment: Updated the xpath to include only span childs.

Comment: //label[@for='someText']/span//span will give direct/indirect children, we need to use //label[@for='someText']/span/span to get only direct children